# how to use bootstrap in another file with framework laravel?

Tags: php, html, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.8

i have file bootstrap, sintaks bootstrap in file layout.backend. one from menu name is form sederhana. in form sederhana there is input makanan for insert new data. when i click input makanan, there is no desain from bootstrap folder backend and folder input makanan are different. how i relate bootstrap in input makanan ?
this is input makanan[image]

and this is view

```
@extends('layout.backend')

@section('title','Dashboard')

@section('content')

    <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->
        <section class="content-header">
            <h1>
                Latihan Laravel
                <small>it all starts here</small>
            </h1>
            <ol class="breadcrumb">
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Examples</a></li>
                <li class="active">Blank page</li>
            </ol>
        </section>

        <!-- Main content -->
        <section class="content">

            <!-- Default box -->
            <div class="box">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <h3 class="box-title">Membuat data di laravel</h3>

                    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse" data-toggle="tooltip"
                                title="Collapse">
                            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Remove">
                            <i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="{{ Route('jenis') }}" class="btn btn-success">Tambah Jenis Makanan</a>
                <a href="{{ Route('input') }}" class="btn btn-primary">Input Makanan</a>
                <br>
                <br>
                @if(count($errors)>0)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        @foreach($errors->all() as $error)
                            {{ $error }}
                            <br/>
                        @endforeach
                    </div>
                @endif

                <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="1%">File</th>
                        <th>Nama Makanan</th>
                        <th>Jenis Makanan</th>
                        <th>Paket</th>
                        <th>Jenis Pembayaran</th>
                        <th>OPSI</th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    @foreach($makanan as $m)
                        <tr>
                            <td><img width="150px" src="{{ url('/image_file/'.$m->file) }}"></td>
                            <td>{{$m->nama_makanan}}</td>
                            <td>{{$m->jenis_makan}}</td>
                            <td>{{$m->paket}}</td>
                            <td>{{$m->pembayaran}}</td>
                            <td>
                                <a class="btn btn-warning" href="/form/edit/{{ $m->id_makanan}}">Edit</a>
                                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="/form/hapus/{{$m->id_makanan}}">Hapus</a>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
                    <div class="box-footer">
                        Footer
                    </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>

@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

You should have your assets in `public` folder, then link them in your `backend.blade.php`
like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```

the structure: `public/css`.